# Simple golang program doesn't run

Tags: go

Here is a simple golang script T1.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world")
}
```

run it with `go run T1.go`, I get:

```
T1.go:1:15: expected ';', found 'import'
```

If I added `;` to line end, the program is okay to run:

```
package main;

import "fmt";

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world")
}
```

But isn't the semicolon redundant of line ending in golang?

PS: I am on 64bit window 7, the golang version is `devel +f4d1cb8d9a91` or **1.2rc1**. The *error* code runs perfect on http://play.golang.org/

**Updates** I've used `dos2unix` to convert the source code to unix line ending, but it doesn't change anything

**Notes** My go is installed in `C:\go` directory and the `C:\go\bin` is added into the `%PATH%` environment variable; The source code `T1.go` is put inside the `C:\t\go` directory, which is different from the go installation directory. Not sure if this configuration contribute to the issue.

Comment: I've uploaded an video records the weird experience with go: http://www.screenr.com/OQtH

Comment: Post the hex dump of your source code. I bet you are using some strange editor which does ugly stuff to your code.

Comment: I use notepad2 and notepad++, both the same result. Hex dump of hello.go file shown in the video: http://pastebin.com/59H8ukXV, and hex dump of the T1.go file shown in the video: http://pastebin.com/qGdVuMFd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Hex dump shows that you are using Carriage Return characters (U+000D) instead of LineFeeds (U+000A) in the `T1.go` file. Using only CR as End-of-line is an old Mac way of doing it.

The [specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Characters) states that a new line is a single line feed character. Since this is not found, the parser assumes it is all written on the same line. In such a case, the compiler requires that you actually type out the semi-colons.

**Solution**

Change your CR to LF and it should work.

If you use Notepad++, you can do this conversion in the menu Edit - EOL Conversion - Unix/OSX Format.

`go fmt` does not convert CR to LF, while it does convert CRLF to LF.
The same goes for `dos2unix`. In your case, it should work with `mac2unix`.

Comment: Thanks @ANisus. That's weird, don't understand how it comes to mac way. But anyway I tried mac2unix, there is no error reporting on parsing stage now. But it displays the `go.exe has stopped working` dialog like it is shown in the video for `hello.go` file.

Comment: @green One problem down, one to go! My answer only deals with T1.go . The error in the video is a separate problem that has me stumped. I will return if I have some theory ;)

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like a bug in the `1.2rc1` version. Try the `1.2rc2` and see if the problem is still there.